# Redundancy in django's urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

In `urls.py` I find myself doing a lot of this:

```
url(r'^show_comments/?$', 'show_comments', name='show_comments')
```

where I repeat the same string three times.
Is there a commonly-used shorthand for this pattern or should I go ahead and write my own?

Comment: hmm. good question. this is what I do all the time too. never thought much about an alternative way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there is a built-in shorthand for this, no.

---

However, I'm not sure it would be desirable to even do so.
Consider the following:

- It's useful to decouple the URL from the function itself if you want to change the function but no the URL in the future *(so as not to break links)*.
- A name isn't required. Unless you're going to be using `reverse`, in which case it's useful to decouple the URL and the function. *(In your example here, it's totally redundant)*
- You would have to import the function and not use its name if you use class-based views / URL-level decorators.
- It's going to take some time for developers coming to your project to adapt to your way of creating URLs if you don't do it the "standard" way.